# How to align the assembly in Siemens NX?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

I rotated the assembly somehow and when I try to make a technical drawing of the assembly this happens:

[image]

As you can see, the cylinder ( assembly ) makes an angle.
How can I fix it ?